# Initial value in loops

Tags: scala, recursion

Suppose you are writing a tail-recursive loop function to evaluate a collection of elements according to some criterium and want to end up with the element that scores best, and its score.

Naturally you will pass the best scoring element so far, as well as its score, as parameters to the function.

But since there is no best element at the start of the recursion, what should you initially pass as parameters to the loop function?  Not wanting to use null, you could use `Option[T]` as parameter types, but then you have to check for `isEmpty` at each recursion while you know that it always has a value after the initial call.  Isn't there a better way?

Comment: Could you do something like `( xs map ( x => (score(x),x) ) ).max` ?

Comment: This looks good, but one downside is that you'll need to iterate over the collection twice.

Comment: Definitely! If your app runs too slowly and profiling reveals that this code contributes significantly to the problem, then you'll want to [trade off maintainability for performance](http://nicholassterling.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/scala-performance/).  In that case a tail-recursive solution of 3 arguments -- xs, hiScore, and hiScorer -- would almost certainly be the best performer that would give you access to both the high scorer and its score, as herman requested.

Comment: I suppose I should add that if the `xs` don't have an Ordering, or if they are very expensive to compare (the above would compare them for tie scores), you can take the max of just the scores like so:
`( xs map ( x => (score(x),x) ) ).maxBy(_._1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use list.head as initial value and loop over list. The first evaluation will be "wasted" since you're evaluating list.head against itself but that will calculate the score for list.head and the rest of the iteration can carry on and do what you want.

Comment: This would mean that any element in the list.tail scores better than list.head, which is not necessarily correct.

Comment: But using `list.head` as initial value and looping over `list` will cause the score for `list.head` to be re-evaluated to the correct value.  If you change your answer to reflect this, I'll accept it.

Comment: @herman good point. I got confused and thought we would use the initial value just to get started. Fixed.

Comment: Note that calling `head` on an empty list will throw an exception.

Comment: @KevinMeredith True, I think that's the behavior one would want in that case. Otherwise, it is easy enough to call `headOption` instead and change the return type of the function to `Option[T]`.

Comment: @vptheron, from a `FP` perspective, I don't believe throwing exceptions is ever **correct**. Consider these words: `The functional solution, of returning errors
as values, is safer, retains RT, and through use of higher order functions, we can
preserve the primary benefit of exceptions—consolidation of error-handling logic.` **-Functional Programming in Scala**  http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/

Comment: @KevinMeredith 1) then how come list.head throws an exception? 2) Scala is not a purely functional language, it is blending oop and fp 3) I agree that avoiding exceptions is usually better, but everyone can decide what's best for their use case.

Comment: Recently I implemented `max` in Haskell. Learn You a Haskell mentions using the `fold11` method, which has no starting value - it simply starts with the first item in the list. The pitfall - it throws an exception when called with an empty list. I don't see how allowing exceptional behavior is comparable to this answer - `def max(xs: List[Long]): Long =
        xs.foldLeft(Long.MinValue){ (acc, elem) => if(elem > acc) elem else acc}`

Answer (score 0):

How is a "best element" evaluated?

Typically that is done through a numeric value.

At the start, you typically set that value to a number.  Best practices state that the number should be defined as a constant, something like the name of MIN_VALUE.  That value could be zero, negative, or the minimum floating point number that is representable.

Comment: I think a link is appropriate for your `Best practices state ...` claim

Answer (score 0):

The head of the list, as `@vptheron` answered, seems to be the best as you don't have a good starting value.

But, rather than use a tail-recursive function...

```
def getBestScore(scores: List[A]): A = {
  def go(as: List[A], acc: A): A = as match {
    case x :: xs => go(xs, getBest(acc, x)) // getBest: ((A, A) => A)
    case Nil => acc
 }
 go(scores, scores.head)
}
```

... you can use `foldLeft` to make it concise.

`val best = scores.foldLeft(scores.head)(getBest)`

Example:

```
scala> def getBest(x: Int, y: Int) = if(x > y) x else y
getBest: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> val scores = List(1, 20, 3)
scores: List[Int] = List(1, 20, 3)

scala> scores.foldLeft(scores.head)(getBest)
res6: Int = 20
```

Comment: Remember that one of the requirements was for the algorithm to yield both the high scorer *and* its score.  Of course, _if it is safe to assume that the score is not expensive to produce_, you could just recalculate it after finding the high scorer.

Comment: @AmigoNico, I suppose that if score would be expensive to produce (not likely: if the list is long, it's only a fraction of the total time anyway) one could always zip with the score and then do the foldLeft on the result of that, right?  This seems like a very good answer.

Comment: --> or map to (element, score) and then foldLeft on that.  

+1 for making me think outside the box :)  That's the trouble I'm having with Scala: always so many ways to do things.

Comment: Sounds like you're making good progress, herman!  BTW, in some applications, producing a score involves accesses to a database -- hence my comment.